# Access - 2013, correct data format for variable uk phone numbers

Tags: ms-access

I am new to this, I have a number of data files that contain UK phone numbers with various issues, such as 0044, +44, missing the leading zero, etc.

Is there a way to remove if it is any of the cases above and replace it with only a zero

Many thanks

Remon

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Replace` function

```
UPDATE tbl 
SET PhoneNo= REPLACE(PhoneNo, '+44', '0')
WHERE PhoneNo like '+44%'
```

This will only affect the records with `+44`. Similarly, you can use it for 0044

Answer (score 0):

Use the Switch function.
Example, assuming your table is called tblUKTelNrs (adjust according to your specific requirements):

```
UPDATE tblUKTelNrs 
SET telNr = Switch(telNr LIKE "0044*","044" & Mid(telNr,5), 
telNr LIKE "+44*","044" & Mid(TelNr,4), telNr LIKE "44*","044" & Mid(TelNr,3))
WHERE telNr NOT LIKE "044*"
```